# Show that the language is regular

Tags: regular-language

Given a regular language L on the input alphabet Σ, and X a subset of Σ*, show that the language {$w$:$w$ $\epsilon$ L, there is a x $\epsilon$ X so that $wx$ $\epsilon$ L} is also regular. Could you help me showing this, because I got stuck..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you get stuck? I admit, this one does sound pretty tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $M$ be a DFA for $L$. $M'$, will be a DFA for the new language. It will be exactly the same as $M$ except for its set of acceptor states. A state $q$ should be an acceptor state in $M'$ if and only if it has an $x$-transition for some $x\in X$ to a state that is ... ?

When I say that $M$ and $M'$ have an $x$-transition from a state $q$ to a state $q'$, I mean that that if the machine is in state $q$ and reads the input word $x$, it ends up in state $q'$. If you’re familiar with the extended transition function $\delta^*$, I mean that $\delta^*(q,x)=q'$.

Comment: ...if and only if it has an x-transition for some x∈X to a state that is an acceptor state in $M$.
Is this right?

Comment: @Mary: That’s right.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Mary: You’re welcome!